# Error: Index out of range taking subset of variable

Tags: r, jags, unmarked-package

I'm rather new to JAGS.
My data consists of larval counts of 5 streams during 15 weeks (two observations / week and stream). For this I work with an array with 150 rows, 2 columns and 15 entries (y). My goal is to estimate omega for each week with help of an open N-mixture model.
I also tried it with the unmarked package but could not figure it out how this would work with pcountopen().

```
sink("model1.txt") 
cat("
model {
# Priors
  lambda ~ dunif(0, 5)
  omega ~ dunif(0, 1)
  p ~ dunif(0, 1)
# Likelihood
  # Biological (ecological) model for true abundance (State model)
  for (i in 1:R) {                  #loop over R sites (150)
  N[i,1] ~ dpois(lambda)            #Abundance
  for (k in 2:15) {                 #loop over weeks (15)
   N[i,k] ~ dpois(omega[k] * N[i, k-1])
   # Observation model for replicated counts
   for (j in 1:T){                  #loop over temporal reps (2)
     y[i,j,k-1] ~ dbin(p, N[i,k-1]) #Detection
     } #j
   } #k
 } #i
}
",fill = TRUE)
sink()

# Bundle and summarize data set 
R = nrow(y) #sites = 150
T = ncol(y) #replications per observation day = 2
win.data <- list(y = y, R = R, T = T)

# Initial values 
Nst <- apply(y, c(1,3), max) +1
inits <- function() {list(N = Nst)}

# Parameters monitored
params1 <- c("omega", "lambda", "p")

# MCMC settings 
ni <- 20 ; nt <- 1 ; nb <- 0 ; nc <- 8

# Call JAGS (ART 1 min) and summarize posteriors 
library(jagsUI)
fm1 <- jags(win.data, inits, params1, 
            "model1.txt", 
            n.chains = nc, n.thin = nt, n.iter = ni, n.burnin = nb)
```

This gives me the following error:
**Error in jags.model(file = model.file, data = data, inits = inits, n.chains = n.chains,  :
RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 12.
Index out of range taking subset of  omega**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: From a quick glance; you have a prior  on a single omega, but then index it up to k; maybe try using `for(i in 1:K){omega[i]~dunif(0,1)}` as the prior?